# How to apply a complex function to every row of a .csv file in MATLAB?

Tags: function, matlab, rows, chaos

I would like to apply an external code with a particualr function (`chaos`; https://figshare.com/s/80891dfb34c6ee9c8b34) from a paper by Toker et al. 2020 (https://www.nature.com/articles/s42003-019-0715-9#Sec1) in order to test whether my data are stochastic or chaotic.

I tried loops,  *for*, `cellfun`, but none of these work in this case.

When I tried to use the following code:

```
T = readtable('ibfrq3.csv');
C = table2array(T);
D = num2cell(C, 2);
rowSums = cellfun(@sum, D)
chaos = cellfun(@chaos, D)
```

I received three errors:

```
Unable to perform assignment because the size of the left side is 1-by-14 and the size of the right side is
1-by-3.

Error in chaos>surrogate (line 989)
        surr(k,:)=unwrap(horzcat(st,parts{randperm(j)},en));

Error in chaos (line 157)
            [surr, params] = surrogate(zscore(surr_y), num_surr, 'CPP', 1, 1);
```

Interestingly, I am able to make the function work, but only for separate rows (by copying them into square brackets and labelling as y e.g. `y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,5,6,7,8,8]`).

My desired output is a string (or ideally a column added to my .csv) with `chaos` function outputs (one word per row: 'stochastic' or 'chaotic' depending on the result).

My data are available here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I2BChrv0iqNr1dcEKTQKxKF7DDl_hF23/view?usp=sharing
The .csv consists of allele frequencies over different time periods.

EDIT:
Trying

```
numRows = size(C, 1);
for row = 1:numRows
    result(row) = chaos(C(row,:));
end
```

Yielded similar errors as above.

I also tried to run the code row by row on my data to check which row causes problems using

```
row1 = C(1,:);
chaos(row1)
```

for every row. Interestingly, it works perfectly giving the desired output for rows no.1, 3-9, 11-100. Rows no.2 and no.10 are not different from the others and do not contain any special characters or values. I have no clue what's wrong with them.

Comment: You mentioned trying some solutions. Present your attempts here, with all the error details included. See [ask] for more advice

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`cellfun` (and its close relative `arrayfun`) are not suitable here because they apply a function to each element of an array separately, while you want to apply a function to each row. Also, you're assigning a value to `chaos` which is already the name of a function, which is likely to lead to confusing behaviour.

If `C` is an *m* x *n* numeric array, and `chaos` is a function that takes a row vector as input and returns a scalar value as output, then

```
numRows = size(C, 1);
for row = 1:numRows
    result(row) = chaos(C(row,:));
end
```

will create a 1 x *m* vector `result` containing the output of the function for each row of `C`.

If the `chaos` function returns a character vector, you'll need to store the result in a cell array instead, by changing the line inside the loop to

```
result{row} = chaos(C(row,:));
```

However the error message you've added to your question suggests there's another issue, because it tells us that an operation inside the `chaos` function is failing. If you say that `chaos` seems to work OK when you give it one row of data at a time, then either your array `C` doesn't contain what you think it does, or there's a row of data that causes it to fail for some reason. You need to debug this. For a start you could add a `disp(row)` inside the loop, which will show you which row of `C` causes the error.

Comment: Thanks for claryfying it! Unfortunately it did not work.